# How to write an Electron app with Hyper?

Tags: electron, hyper

I was wondering, how can I start to write an [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) app using the [Hyper.js](https://github.com/zeit/hyper) sources?

I am new to both Electron and Hyper, and watched a few videos on building an Electron app. But I can't quite figure out how to start the Hyper app. For instance, which is the "main" file in the sources?

Comment: Start off by looking at the scripts section of the package.json file in the root directory, you can see to initialise the app you run `electron app`? In the app directory the index.js file contains most of the code relative to the apps execution via electron?

Comment: Thanks Craig, the [package.json](https://github.com/zeit/hyper/blob/canary/app/package.json) file was the first to have looked in, but there is no "scripts" section in that file (which I was surprised not to see, but since I am a beginner I guess there is something I don't yet understand). And I tried  `node index.js` but it complains with an error about notify.js, that it cannot read a property 'on' of undefined, in the line: `app.on('ready', () => {`.

Comment: (I've edited this to make it less about requesting a guide, as that would be off-topic. It's a bit brief, but it may yet pass, given that it has upvotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after more reading and getting familiar with Node.js and Electron apps, the following procedure works:

`git clone https://github.com/zeit/hyper
cd hyper
npm install`

A lot of packages will be installed in a subdirectory called node_modules, then:

`yarn run dev`

And (in a separate terminal window):

`yarn rup app`

This will open an Electron app similar to the original one built by [Hyper](https://hyper.is/).